# Missing assembly or reference for htmlhelpers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm having a problem that VS (2015) complains about some things i my .cshtml views.

> "The name 'model' does not exist in the current context"

```
@model Project.MyModel
```

> 'HtmlHelper' doesn not contain a definition for a 'TextBoxFor' and no extension method 'TextBoxFor' accepting a first argument of type 'HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.Property)
```

I can't figure out why it's like this.

My Views/Web.config

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

My Web.config

```
pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing"/>
    <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/>
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

Can anyone see what I'm missing here?

EDIT: It works fine in VS 2013..

Comment: Have you tried to close and reopen this file?

Comment: Check all your `<bindingRedirect .. newVersion=".." />` against all you version numbers in the web.config file for a version mismatch

Comment: whats your .Net target framework?

Comment: 4.5. Please see my edit. It works fine in VS 2013

Comment: `<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />`
Try changing above value `3.0.0.0` to `2.0.0.0` in your web.config. Build solution and open the view.

Comment: @Manthan It is at 2.0.0.0, I can try 3.0.0.0

Comment: Try creating a new MVC project using same framework version 4.5 just to look at default web.config settings. Observe both Views/web.config and main web.config. Compare with your project's web.config settings. Found any difference ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed this guide and it now works. It looks like I was missing some version upgrades...

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2

Look in packages.config and check what version of Microsoft.Aso.Net.Mvc you have. Then in Views/Web.config I changed the version number into that in these places (in my case I added Version=5.2.3.0):

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
</system.web.webPages.razor>

<system.web>
<pages
    validateRequest="false"
    pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
    pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
    userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
  <controls>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" />
  </controls>
</pages>
</system.web>
```

I also upgraded the version number from Version=2.0.0.0 -> Version=3.0.0.0 here (Still Views/Web.config):

```
<configSections>
<sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
  <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
  <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
</sectionGroup>
</configSections>
```

Comment: If it's possible add content to your answer instead of linking it, please. That article can become unavailable and your answer will lose any value.

Answer (score 1):

Build Your Code in static class in folder named it for example helpers
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46DDz.png)

then 
go and add this folder in the  web.config  like this

add namespace="TheCompeleteApp.Helper"

If it didn't work  go and hard coded it in the view that you using this extension method in like this
@using FinalProject_0._1.Helper